# Pivot and Transpose Pandas Dataframe dynamically from nested JSON

Tags: python, pandas

I have a nested JSON looking like below:

Input JSON:

```
data= {
  "name": "root",
  "type": {"sample":"text"},
  "teacher": [
    {
      "name": "properties",
      "type": "feature",
      "father": [
        {
          "name": "print",
          "type": "feature",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "graphic print",
              "type": "feature",
              "inherits": "true"
            },
            {
              "name": "striped print",
              "type": "feature",
              "inherits": "true",
              "sister": [
                {
                  "name": "pinstriped",
                  "type": "feature",
                  "inherits": "true"
                },
                {
                  "name": "light stripe",
                  "type": "feature",
                  "inherits": "true"
                },
                {
                  "name": "wide stripe",
                  "type": "feature",
                  "inherits": "true"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "colours",
      "type": "colour",
      "father": [
        {
          "name": "main colours",
          "type": "colour",
          "reacher": [
            {
              "name": "black",
              "type": "colour",
              "sister": [
                {
                  "name": "light black",
                  "type": "colour",
                  "inherits": "true"
                },
                {
                  "name": "blue black",
                  "type": "colour",
                  "inherits": "true"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "red",
              "type": "colour",
              "teacher": [
                {
                  "name": "bright red",
                  "type": "colour",
                  "inherits": "true"
                },
                {
                  "name": "light red",
                  "type": "colour"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "genders",
      "type": "gender",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "female",
          "type": "gender"
        },
        {
          "name": "male",
          "type": "gender"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

By creating tree traversal code i can fetch all the keys and value of the JSON but now cannot group columns as they are too much normalized

I am using below code on my jSON:

```
import pandas as pd
def nested_parser(indict, pre=None):
    pre = pre[:] if pre else []
    if isinstance(indict, dict):
        for key, value in indict.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for d in nested_parser(value, pre + [key+'_dict']):
                    yield d
            elif isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, tuple):
                for idx,v in enumerate(value):
                    for d in nested_parser(v, pre + [key+'_array_'+str(idx)]):
                        yield d
            else:
                yield pre + [key, value]
    else:
        yield pre + [indict]
lst = [i for i in nested_parser(data)]
max_dept_elem = len(max(lst, key=len))
padded_list = [i[:-1]+ [None] * (max_dept_elem-len(i)) + i[-1:] if len(i)<max_dept_elem else i for i in lst]
df = pd.DataFrame(padded_list)
df_cols = ["root_level_"+str(col) for col in df.columns.values]
df.columns = df_cols
print(df)
```

mainly this is achieved by complex traversal of dictionary that has lots of list and this way it is working fast. I cannot flatten and explode much faster so using traversal for flattening of complex JSON

```
      root_level_0      root_level_1      root_level_2     root_level_3 root_level_4   root_level_5
0              name              None              None             None         None           root
1         type_dict            sample              None             None         None           text
2   teacher_array_0              name              None             None         None     properties
3   teacher_array_0              type              None             None         None        feature
4   teacher_array_0    father_array_0              name             None         None          print
5   teacher_array_0    father_array_0              type             None         None        feature
6   teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_0             name         None  graphic print
7   teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_0             type         None        feature
8   teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_0         inherits         None           true
9   teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1             name         None  striped print
10  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1             type         None        feature
11  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1         inherits         None           true
12  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1   sister_array_0         name     pinstriped
13  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1   sister_array_0         type        feature
14  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1   sister_array_0     inherits           true
15  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1   sister_array_1         name   light stripe
16  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1   sister_array_1         type        feature
17  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1   sister_array_1     inherits           true
18  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1   sister_array_2         name    wide stripe
19  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1   sister_array_2         type        feature
20  teacher_array_0    father_array_0  children_array_1   sister_array_2     inherits           true
21  teacher_array_1              name              None             None         None        colours
22  teacher_array_1              type              None             None         None         colour
23  teacher_array_1    father_array_0              name             None         None   main colours
24  teacher_array_1    father_array_0              type             None         None         colour
25  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_0             name         None          black
26  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_0             type         None         colour
27  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_0   sister_array_0         name    light black
28  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_0   sister_array_0         type         colour
29  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_0   sister_array_0     inherits           true
30  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_0   sister_array_1         name     blue black
31  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_0   sister_array_1         type         colour
32  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_0   sister_array_1     inherits           true
33  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_1             name         None            red
34  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_1             type         None         colour
35  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_1  teacher_array_0         name     bright red
36  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_1  teacher_array_0         type         colour
37  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_1  teacher_array_0     inherits           true
38  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_1  teacher_array_1         name      light red
39  teacher_array_1    father_array_0   reacher_array_1  teacher_array_1         type         colour
40  teacher_array_2              name              None             None         None        genders
41  teacher_array_2              type              None             None         None         gender
42  teacher_array_2  children_array_0              name             None         None         female
43  teacher_array_2  children_array_0              type             None         None         gender
44  teacher_array_2  children_array_1              name             None         None           male
45  teacher_array_2  children_array_1              type             None         None         gender
```

I have also tried grouping and collecting as list but dont know how to proceed further to convert these columns to rows.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['root_level_0','root_level_1','root_level_2','root_level_3','root_level_4'])['root_level_5'].apply(list)
print(grouped_df)


root_level_0     root_level_1    root_level_2      root_level_3     root_level_4
teacher_array_0  father_array_0  children_array_1  sister_array_0   inherits                [true]
                                                                    name              [pinstriped]
                                                                    type                 [feature]
                                                   sister_array_1   inherits                [true]
                                                                    name            [light stripe]
                                                                    type                 [feature]
                                                   sister_array_2   inherits                [true]
                                                                    name             [wide stripe]
                                                                    type                 [feature]
teacher_array_1  father_array_0  reacher_array_0   sister_array_0   inherits                [true]
                                                                    name             [light black]
                                                                    type                  [colour]
                                                   sister_array_1   inherits                [true]
                                                                    name              [blue black]
                                                                    type                  [colour]
                                 reacher_array_1   teacher_array_0  inherits                [true]
                                                                    name              [bright red]
                                                                    type                  [colour]
                                                   teacher_array_1  name               [light red]
                                                                    type                  [colour]
```

I have tried multiple things but not able to achieve data frame like below:

```
   name type.sample teacher.name teacher.type  ... teacher.father.reacher.teacher.type teacher.father.reacher.teacher.inherits teacher.children.name teacher.children.type
0  root        text   properties      feature  ...                                 NaN                                     NaN                   NaN                   NaN
1  root        text   properties      feature  ...                                 NaN                                     NaN                   NaN                   NaN
2  root        text   properties      feature  ...                                 NaN                                     NaN                   NaN                   NaN
3  root        text   properties      feature  ...                                 NaN                                     NaN                   NaN                   NaN
4  root        text      colours       colour  ...                                 NaN                                     NaN                   NaN                   NaN
5  root        text      colours       colour  ...                                 NaN                                     NaN                   NaN                   NaN
6  root        text      colours       colour  ...                              colour                                    true                   NaN                   NaN
7  root        text      colours       colour  ...                              colour                                     NaN                   NaN                   NaN
8  root        text      genders       gender  ...                                 NaN                                     NaN                female                gender
9  root        text      genders       gender  ...                                 NaN                                     NaN                  male                gender
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: Can you clarify the structure of your source dataframe?

Comment: @Uzebeckatrente i have edited the question with proper details. any help will be great...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated for child name agnosticism**

This should do what you're looking for:

```
rows = []
def processData(data, prefix = "root", row = dict(), doEmit = True):
    #add a column for each new attribute
    hasChildren = False
    for k in data.keys():
        if type(data[k]) == str:
            colName = prefix + "_" + k
            row[colName] = data[k]
        elif type(data[k]) == dict:
            prefix += "_" + k
            child = data[k]
            processData(child,prefix = prefix, row = row, doEmit = False);
    for k in data.keys():
        if type(data[k]) == list:
            hasChildren = True
            #update prefix
            prefix += "_" + k
            for child in data[k]:
                processData(child,prefix = prefix, row = row.copy());
    if not hasChildren and doEmit:
        #finished row when there is no child
        rows.append(row);
        return


processData(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df)
```

Comment: can it be independent of key string "children". As i have different keys that have arrays. This JSON is just an example

Comment: i have updated the JSON with different keys

Comment: I made the corresponding changes

Comment: If you have questions about how it works lmk! I hope you will be able to do this yourself next time :)

Comment: pls have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76898018/how-to-convert-a-nested-json-consisting-of-lists-dicts-strs-and-none-to-pandas