# How to convert a nested JSON consisting of lists, ints, dicts, strs and None to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following JSON structure,

```
{
   'total_numbers': 2,
   'data':[
      {
         'col3':'2',
         'col4':[
            {
               'col5':'P',
               'col6':'H'
            }
         ],
         'col7':'2023-06-19T09:29:28.786Z',
         'col9':{
            'col10':'TEST',
            'col11':'test@email.com',
            'col12':'True',
            'col13':'999',
            'col14':'9999'
         },
         'col15':'2023-07-10T04:46:43.003Z',
         'col16':False,
         'col17':[
            {
               'col18':'S',
               'col19':'H'
            }
         ],
         'col20':True,
         'col21':{
            'col22':'sss',
            'col23':'0.0.0.0',
            'col24':'lll'
         },
         'col25':0,
         'col26':{
            'col27':{
               'col28':'Other'
            },
            'col29':'Other',
            'col30':'cccc'
         },
         'col31':{
            'col32':[
               {
                  'col33':'123456789',
                  'col34':'2023-07-14T02:52:20.166Z',
                  'col36':True,
                  'col38':{
                     'col40':[
                        {
                           'col41':'99999999999',
                        },
                        {
                           'col41':'34534543535',
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  'col55':'878787878'
               },
               {
                  'col47':'112233445566',
                  'col48':'2023-07-24T09:26:03.425Z',
                  'col50':True,
                  'col52':{
                     'col53':[
                        {
                           'col54':'99999999999',
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  'col55':'878787878'
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         'col3':'2',
         'col4':[
            {
               'col5':'P',
               'col6':'H'
            }
         ],
         'col7':'2023-06-19T09:29:28.786Z',
         'col9':{
            'col10':'TEST',
            'col11':'test@email.com',
            'col12':'True',
            'col13':'999',
            'col14':'9999'
         },
         'col15':'2023-07-10T04:46:43.003Z',
         'col16':False,
         'col17':[
            {
               'col18':'S',
               'col19':'H'
            }
         ],
         'col20':True,
         'col21':{
            'col22':'sss',
            'col23':'0.0.0.0',
            'col24':'lll'
         },
         'col25':0,
         'col26':{
            'col27':{
               'col28':'Other'
            },
            'col29':'Other',
            'col30':'cccc'
         },
         'col31':{
            'col32':[
               {
                  'col33':'123456789',
                  'col34':'2023-07-14T02:52:20.166Z',
                  'col36':True,
                  'col38':{
                     'col40':[
                        {
                           'col41':'99999999999',
                        },
                        {
                           'col41':'34534543535',
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  'col55':'878787878'
               },
               {
                  'col47':'112233445566',
                  'col48':'2023-07-24T09:26:03.425Z',
                  'col50':True,
                  'col52':{
                     'col53':[
                        {
                           'col54':'99999999999',
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  'col55':'878787878'
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there a dynamic function I could use to convert this structure to tabular form based on traversing through the JSON?

**I came across this function** (marked as [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72549493/14291703)) which i think could be helpful for my case. In the example I understand there will be 6 rows based on the number of levels in the json though I don't understand the naming of some columns. The data is there but the column names are not correct a/c to its level. Is there any update I could make to the function to achieve this?

For example, the name of the columns should be actually root_data_col4_col5 and root_data_col4_col6

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about the structure of the data you're hoping to get out. Is it guaranteed that the lists will only ever contain one item and that item will be a dict?

Comment: The lists will always have a guaranteed dict within. Could be more than 1 dict as given in the example. But each dict, within that list can again have a list and dict and so on. So i was looking for a dynamic function that could handle this scenario based on the type the loop will be traversing. I found this function (linked in the ques) closest to my needs.

Comment: Sorry, but in the example all the lists have exactly one dict in them. If there are 2 dicts in one list then the column names will have to reflect which item was selected, like:
 'root_data_col4_item0_col5': 'P',
 'root_data_col4_item0_col6': 'H',

Comment: Oh I meant ,for example, col32 is a list and has two dicts. So therefore, the column names should be -> col31_col32_col33, and so on.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see that one in my browser - since the column names are unique it's an easy fix.

Comment: Check out my answer now - is that what you were looking for? I don't understand what the criteria for a new row is. The above has unique keys for every indexing, so there doesn't seem to be any need to make rows. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attempt. For the new row, the json will have the above structure (from col3 till end) separated by commas under data list. I also checked that there could be cases where the column names could be the same especially when there two dicts within a list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254906/discussion-between-andrew-louw-and-royalewithcheese).

Answer (score 0):

The following works in 2 steps:
firstly it breaks the JSON into alternating dicts and lists - removing all dictionaries containing dictionaries as top level values.
It then parses this new structure so that whenever there is a list (and hence the potential for duplicate keys) it creates a new row item for each element. Doing things this way results in 2 rows with data in them for 'root_data_col31_col32_col55' which I think is the intended behaviour.

```py
import pandas as pd

def flatten_dict(x, key="root"):
    result = {}
    # assume we have a dict
    for k, v in x.items():
        new_key = key + "_" + k
        if isinstance(v, list):
            tmp = [flatten_dict(i, new_key) for i in v]
            result[new_key] = tmp
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            tmp = flatten_dict(v, key=new_key)
            result.update(tmp)
        else:
            if k == "col32":
                print(v)
            result[new_key] = v
    return result

def parse_dict(flat_dict):
    tmp = {}
    result = [tmp]
    for k, v in flat_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for item in v:
                result += parse_dict(item)
        else:
            tmp[k] = v
    return result

z = flatten_dict(x)
y = parse_dict(z)
df = pd.DataFrame(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem before and made a code that converts Json/Dict/List to a way that can be used in pandas dataframe.

when I saw your problem, I uploaded the code to github to make you able to clone it, also I got tons of ideas after I read @Andrew Louw code, so I uploaded the package to PYPI called JsonDF.

download the package via pip

```
pip install JsonDF
```

or from [GitHub](https://github.com/OsamaElsherif/JsonDF)

and I've no problem with contributions, so feel free to make anything.

that's the code based on your problem

```
from JsonDf.Data import Data
import pandas as pd

data = Data(prefix='root', data=JsonData['data'])
data.childs()
data.flatten()
rows = data.rows

print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(rows), orient="columns").transpose())
```

the output was like that :

[image: output image]

**EDIT**

for the new edit you made, you just need to make a smal for loop in it

*jsonData variable with the Json above as a value for it*

```py
from JsonDF.Data import Data
import pandas as pd

all_rows = []
for i in range(jsonData['total_numbers']):
   data = Data(data=jsonData['data'][i])
   data.childs()
   data.flatten()
   all_rows.append(data.rows_flatten)

#print(all_rows)

print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(all_rows), orient="columns").transpose())
```

the result will be :

[image: another output]

Comment: I have edited my question. How will the output look like then?

Comment: can you tell me where is the edit exacatlly please ?

Comment: I have edited the json in my question.

Comment: sorrym my mistake, I found the edirt I will show you the code for it, and will edit my answer, wait a sec.

Comment: @royalewithcheese check my answer with the edit.