# How to convert nested json to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following JSON structure,

```
{
   'total_numbers': 2,
   'data':[
      {
         'col3':'2',
         'col4':[
            {
               'col5':'P',
               'col6':'H'
            },
            {
               'col5':'P1',
               'col6':'H1'
            },
         ],
         'col7':'2023-06-19T09:29:28.786Z',
         'col9':{
            'col10':'TEST',
            'col11':'test@email.com',
            'col12':'True',
            'col13':'999',
            'col14':'9999'
         },
         'col15':'2023-07-10T04:46:43.003Z',
         'col16':False,
         'col17':[
            {
               'col18':'S',
               'col19':'H'
            }
         ],
         'col20':True,
         'col21':{
            'col22':'sss',
            'col23':'0.0.0.0',
            'col24':'lll'
         },
         'col25':0,
         'col26':{
            'col27':{
               'col28':'Other'
            },
            'col29':'Other',
            'col30':'cccc'
         },
         'col31':{
            'col32':[
               {
                  'col33':'123456789',
                  'col34':'2023-07-14T02:52:20.166Z',
                  'col36':True,
                  'col38':{
                     'col40':[
                        {
                           'col41':'99999999999',
                        },
                        {
                           'col41':'34534543535',
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  'col55':'878787878'
               },
               {
                  'col47':'112233445566',
                  'col48':'2023-07-24T09:26:03.425Z',
                  'col50':True,
                  'col52':{
                     'col53':[
                        {
                           'col54':'99999999999',
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  'col55':'878787878'
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         'col3':'3',
         'col4':[
            {
               'col5':'P',
               'col6':'H'
            }
         ],
         'col7':'2023-06-19T09:29:28.786Z',
         'col9':{
            'col10':'TEST',
            'col11':'test@email.com',
            'col12':'True',
            'col13':'999',
            'col14':'9999'
         },
         'col15':'2023-07-10T04:46:43.003Z',
         'col16':False,
         'col17':[
            {
               'col18':'S',
               'col19':'H'
            }
         ],
         'col20':True,
         'col21':{
            'col22':'sss',
            'col23':'0.0.0.0',
            'col24':'lll'
         },
         'col25':0,
         'col26':{
            'col27':{
               'col28':'Other'
            },
            'col29':'Other',
            'col30':'cccc'
         },
         'col31':{
            'col32':[
               {
                  'col33':'123456789',
                  'col34':'2023-07-14T02:52:20.166Z',
                  'col36':True,
                  'col38':{
                     'col40':[
                        {
                           'col41':'99999999999',
                        },
                        {
                           'col41':'34534543535',
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  'col55':'878787878'
               },
               {
                  'col47':'112233445566',
                  'col48':'2023-07-24T09:26:03.425Z',
                  'col50':True,
                  'col52':{
                     'col53':[
                        {
                           'col54':'99999999999',
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  'col55':'878787878'
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to convert this to a pandas dataframe. Through the resulting dataframe I want to be able to uniquely identify each row using col3.

I have used a few approaches before.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72549493/14291703

Problem: The name of the columns are not correct.

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76898193/14291703

Problem: Cannot uniquely identify each row with col3

What I expect is the following,

Each column represents a level in the json,
data_col3, data_col4_col5, data_col4_col6...

Comment: `col4` is at the same level as `col3` (as are `col7`, `col9`, `col15` etc.) so shouldn't the column names be `data_col3`, `data_col4_col5`, `data_col4_col6` etc.?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the provided JSON structure into a pandas DataFrame and set `col3` as the index to identify each row uniquely. Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Your JSON structure
json_data = {
    # ... (your JSON data here)
}

# Convert JSON to a DataFrame
data = json_data['data']
df = pd.json_normalize(data, sep='_')

# Set 'col3' as the index
df.set_index('col3', inplace=True)

print(df)
```

This code will read the JSON structure, normalize it into a DataFrame, and set the `col3` column as the index. This will allow you to uniquely identify each row using the values in the `col3` column. Make sure you have the `pandas` library installed in your environment.